# How to hook "uc_cart_complete_sale" without broking this ubercart function

Tags: hooks, ubercart

I try to understand the hook system of ubercart but there this something i don't get it at all. My main objective it to add a js code to the page "cart/checkout/complete" to send to an external service the total of an order.

Actually when a new user buy a product, ubercart log the new client automatically, assign him a role so he can download the product. If it's an existing user on the cart/chekout/complete page, we show him a text message on the order complete page telling him to connect to his account to get the product he purchase.

The javascript code the provider give me to add on the "cart/checkout/complete" page is this one:

```
<script> window.optimizely = window.optimizely || [];     window.optimizely.push(['trackEvent', 'purchases', {'revenue': 100}]);    </script>
```

In the revenue parameter of this script, I need to put the total order of the purchase.

What I did to get the total order is to hook the "uc_cart_complete_sale".

So in my template file I create this function:

```
function MY_THEME_NAME_uc_cart_complete_sale($variables) {
  $a0 = arg(0);
  $a1 = arg(1);
  $a2 = arg(2);
  if( $a0 == "cart" && $a1 == "checkout" && $a2 == "complete"){
          $order_json = json_encode($variables[order]->order_total);     $order_json = $order_json * 100;
     // print $order_json;
     drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () {window.optimizely = window.optimizely || []; window.optimizely.push([\'trackEvent\', \'purchases\', {\'revenue\': '.$order_json.'}]);});', 'inline');*/
```

}
     }

I think it's not the best way to do to put this type of function in my template theme file but i don't think of create a custom module only for this type of thing.

When i use this code the script call the external service and notify a sale with the order total.

In part this is working but really it's broking totally the way the client can get his product after.

It's like part of the code of uc_cart_complete_sale are not executed. When i activate this hook code, new client connect to my drupal site as an authenticate user but without the role permission to download the product.

If it's an existing client, i have only the title of the page "Order complete" without any message telling him to connect to his account.

And if he connect with his account he don't have the role permission to get his product.

I dig in the cart.module file to check the uc_cart_complete_sale function in ubercart module but it's like when i hook this function all the $messages variable are emptied and the part of code in charge of assigning a role to client is not executed.

Could you tell me what i'm doing wrong. Maybe i need to do that in an other way but i really don't know how to do that.

Thank you very much for your advices